# Error when Updating to Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to update Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 5.4 that was released yesturday, and I get this message:

```
Problem 1
- laravelcollective/html 5.3.x-dev requires illuminate/view 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.20], illuminate/view[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
- laravelcollective/html 5.3.x-dev requires illuminate/view 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.20], illuminate/view[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
- laravelcollective/html 5.3.x-dev requires illuminate/view 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.20], illuminate/view[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.4.0, v5.3.20].
- don't install illuminate/view v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/view v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/view v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/view v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.4.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.0].
- Installation request for laravelcollective/html 5.3.*-dev -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[5.3.x-dev].
```

Thing is I don't see laravelcollective has release a 5.4 version.

Do I need to wait for them to release new version or am I missing something?

Why isn't it in the upgrade guide, it is a quite important lib in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

You have some options.  Laravel Collective is a popular package, so people are already applying the fixes required for it to work on 5.4.  Check out the following thread on a pull request.

https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/pull/276

So, in order to use the package with 5.4, based on comments in the thread, you'll need to change your composer.json to look like this.

```
"laravel/collective": "5.4.x-dev",
```

Then run `composer update`

If you want you can also use a specific commit.  In this case, to use the commit on this pull request, your composer.json would look like so.

```
"laravelcollective/html": "dev-master#92f3ba71c5c11c752ddd68d614f5f0665e759220",
```

Comment: still can't do it. "laravel/collective": "5.4.x-dev", gives me:     - The requested package laravel/collective could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
and if I replace it to      "laravelcollective/html": "5.4.x-dev",
or with the hash, it gives me the same error :(

Comment: I updated my answer since I had the package name wrong.  It appears this commit is still unstable though.  The owner of the package commented about half an hour ago that he's on it, so you might just want to wait this one out.